# How to read large avro file with out loading entire file into memory

Tags: java, avro

I want to read large avro file of size 2.5 GB. Currently, I'm using

```
new DataFileReader<>(readFile, userDatumReader);
```

Which loads entire 2.5 GB file into memory.

Is there any way to read large avro file with out loading complete file into memory?

Answer (score 0):

Using a DataFileReader should almost certainly *not* load the complete file into memory.

```
DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
try (DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(file, datumReader)) {
  while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
    GenericRecord datum = dataFileReader.next(null)
    processRecord(datum);
    // Make sure you're not keeping a reference
    // to datum after it's been processed.
  }
}
```

I've verified that `datum` can be garbage collected once it's been processed, and should not be kept around in memory by Avro.  Is it possible that you're saving the data in a collection or keeping a reference in your code?  This will, of course, prevent garbage collection.

The other way Avro might read the entire file contents into memory is if there is  only one record of 2.5GB in the Avro file... in this case, you might want to revisit your design for storing data!